# Setting String to "public" C# Web Developer

Tags: c#, web, parent-child, global, public

So I know there is no such thing as a "global" variable in C# but I am trying to pass a string from my site.master page to a child page.  I would like my search button on my master page to pass the value of a textbox on the master page to a "global" string, then have the child page use that "global" string upon page load.  What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You don't need any _"global"_ variable at all. This will help : [Search Results on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+pass+from+master+page+to+child+page)

Comment: Note. While @Felipe below here has given you a correct answer. It is **not** what you should be doing. You should _pass_ the value and design your pages (and page classes) accordingly. Look at the search results and come back here with any doubts you have.

Comment: I think you can do something like this to access master page attr: `(TextBox)(this.SiteMaster.FindControl("textBox1")).Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class named global and define static variables in it to use them globally.

```
class Globals
{
    internal static string str_variable;
}
```

**EDIT**

when you hit search

```
Globals.str_variable = Textbox1.Text;
```

and when you want to retrieve

```
string temp = Globals.str_variable;
```

Comment: If I use this method, how do I assign the textbox to that string?

Comment: when you hit search Globals.str_variable = Textbox1.Text;
and when you want to retrieve string temp = Globals.str_variable;

Comment: Perfect!  I used "string temp = SiteMaster.Globals.str_variable;" and it worked perfect!  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties of your project and change the Access Modifier and Scope of the setting, for sample:

[image]